# how to add space between characters within one textview in android

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

When there is a text view, and there is a sentence called 'HelloWorld' in it, I want to give exactly 10dp space between o and w regardless of font size.

I wanted to solve it with a spanable string, but I failed.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you put two textview?? Do you have to do it in a textview?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan There's a code example there that sets the size of some characters to a *dp* value. If you can work out where to insert your spaces in the string, then you have the locations of your spans